# Is there any way to NSEvent convert to string array or string object?

Tags: swift, cocoa, swiftui, nsevent

This is the code I tried.It gives the mouse Click event in macOS

```
let eventObserver = NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: NSEvent.EventTypeMask.leftMouseDown) { (event) -> Void in
    Swift.print("Event is \(event)")
}
```

when I clicked any place. It gives output

> Event is NSEvent: type=LMouseDown loc=(248.664,269.775) time=12673.2
> flags=0 win=0x0 winNum=91 ctxt=0x0 evNum=905 click=1 buttonNumber=0
> pressure=1 deviceID:0x300000014400000 subtype=NSEventSubtypeTouch

when I checked the output type it says **NSEvent type**. Does anyone know how to convert this to a string array or string object? Because After that I want to convert it to JSON.

Comment: You can just access those various properties for yourself, and write them to a string or JSON payload however you'd like. What are you trying to do with this, exactly?

Comment: I need to save this data in a database. that's why I try to convert it to an array string or object string. How do I access those various properties? I'm new to swift

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent). `event` is an `NSEvent` instance. You can access all listed properties.